# Java 8 Streams: How to match values between two ArrayList of Strings and create a list of another object

Tags: java, java-stream

I am having two lists of Strings and want to compare the values in the lists and construct a new list of another object. I am able to do this with nested loops but looking for a more performant and neater solution.

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList();
list1.add("A,Airplane");
list1.add("B,Boat");

List<String> list2 = new ArrayList();
list2.add("A90, Boing Airplane");
list2.add("A70, Boing777");
list2.add("B80, Boing Boat");
```

There is a Vehicle object.

```
class Vehicle {

private String model;
private String submodel;
private String type;
private String subtype;
// setters getters
}
```

Now, I need to build the vehicle object using by matching the model (the first character from list1) with the first character in list2 and build something like this

```
private List<Vehicle> buildVehicle(List<String> list1, List<String> list2) {
        List<Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList<>();
        if (ObjectUtils.isNotEmpty(list2)) {
            list2.forEach(v -> {
                Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle();
                if (v.contains(",")) {
                    String[] val = StringUtils.split(v,",");
                    vehicle.setSubtype(val[0]);
                    vehicle.setSubmodel(val[1]);
                }
                for (String c : list1) {
                    //Matching the first character from element in list1 
                    if (c.substring(0,1).equals(vehicle.getSubtype().substring(0,1))
                            && c.contains(",")) {
                        String[] val = StringUtils.split(c, ",");
                        vehicle.setType(val[0]);
                        vehicle.setModel(val[1]);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
                vehicles.add(vehicle);
            });
        }
        return vehicles;
    }
```

Can the nested loop be avoided by using streams?

Comment: Note that you might be able to get more compact, readable and a neater solution, but most possibly not a more "performant" one as you mentioned. Performance is mostly determined by the data structures you make use of, and the time/space complexities of your solution. On top of that, stream api is not as optimized and therefore slightly slower than a good old for/while loops.

Comment: Can you please explain on the compact, and neater solution?

Comment: `ObjectUtils` and `StringUtils` are not part of the JDK.

Answer (score 4):

I'd follow an approach like the following:

```java
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
list1.add("A,Airplane");
list1.add("B,Boat");

List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
list2.add("A90, Boing Airplane");
list2.add("A70, Boing777");
list2.add("B80, Boing Boat");

Pattern commaPattern = Pattern
    .compile("\\s*,\\s*"); // a regex pattern to split by comma and the whitespace around it

Map<String, String> modelToType = list1.stream().map(commaPattern::split)
    .collect(Collectors
        .toMap(modelAndType -> modelAndType[0],
            modelAndType -> modelAndType[1])); // mapping models to types for o(1) lookups

List<Vehicle> vehicles = list2.stream().map(commaPattern::split)
    .map(subModelAndSubType -> {
      Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle();
      vehicle.submodel = subModelAndSubType[0];
      vehicle.subtype = subModelAndSubType[1];
      vehicle.model = vehicle.submodel.substring(0, 1);
      vehicle.type = modelToType.get(vehicle.model);
      return vehicle;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The data as provided.

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
list1.add("A,Airplane");
list1.add("B,Boat");

List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
list2.add("A90, Boeing Airplane");
list2.add("A70, Boeing777");
list2.add("B80, Boeing Boat");
```

Regardless of how the model type information is obtained, this conversion might be more efficient and certainly easier if instead of using `Lists` you used `Maps` to hold the information.  If the information was read in from a file it would be best to pre-process them (split if need be)  as they are read in and put them in a map.  If it was entered by hand then putting the information in a map would negate the need for any pre-processing at all. Here is a simple example.

```
Map<String,String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("A","Airplane");
map1.put("B","Boat");
```

However, using the information as provided here is how I proceeded.

First, I created a Lambda to assist in the List conversion.

```
Function<List<String>, Map<String, String>> makeMap =
        lst -> lst.stream().map(st -> st.split("\\s*,\\s*")).collect(
                Collectors.toMap(a -> a[0], a -> a[1]));

// create the TypeModel map
Map<String, String> mapTM = makeMap.apply(list1);
// create the subTypeSubModel Map;
Map<String, String> mapSTSM = makeMap.apply(list2);
```

Now just use the keysets of each to go thru and piece it together.
I created a constructor in my example for `Vehicle` which imho makes
a cleaner object creation.

```
List<Vehicle> vehicles = mapTM.keySet().stream()
        .flatMap(type -> mapSTSM.keySet().stream()
                .filter(subType -> subType.startsWith(type))
                .map(sbType -> new Vehicle(mapTM.get(type),
                        mapSTSM.get(sbType), type, sbType)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

vehicles.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints based on toString (which can be changed).

```
[Airplane, Boeing Airplane,A,A90]
[Airplane, Boeing777,A,A70]
[Boat, Boeing Boat,B,B80]
```

Here is the class sans setters and getters.

```
class Vehicle {
    
    private String model;
    private String submodel;
    private String type;
    private String subtype;
    
    public Vehicle() {
    }
    
    public Vehicle(String model, String submodel, String type,
            String subtype) {
        this.model = model;
        this.submodel = submodel;
        this.type = type;
        this.subtype = subtype;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
       return "[" + String.join(", ", model, submodel, type, subtype)
                + "]";
    }
}
```